# Как развернуть (открыть) war файл в WildFly?

Tags: wildfly, war

Я установил WildFly на свою систему (linux)

Вроде как успешно установил, запустил сервис:

1)

```
sudo sh standalone.sh
```

Появилась приветственная страницаWildFly в браузере

2)

```
https//localhost:8080/
```

3)
Копирую свой варник name.war в wildfly-10.1.0.Final/standalone/deployments

4) Пробую перейти на страницу

```
https//localhost:8080/name
```

И получаю ошибку 404

Мало того - я не могу переходить по ссылкам главной страницы WildFly, если ето не ссылки на внешние ресурсы:

`http://localhost:8080/documentation.html` и прочее мне недоступно.

Как правильно пользоваться `WildFly`?

Comment: Linux локальный или на сервере где-то?

Comment: @Bakhuss, локально

Comment: Сначала через adduser надо создать пользователя, потом уже заходить через web. Почитайте в гугле, я просто с телефона пишу.

Comment: А можно всё это через консоль делать.

Comment: @Bakhuss, вот я и нашел в инете как создавать юзера - необходимо перейти по ссылке в окне WindFly. А ссылки не действительные

Comment: Нет, это делается через утилиту в папке bin папки Wildfly. При запущенном standalone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы управлять wildfly через web, предварительно надо создать пользователя используя утилиту add-user.sh (или .bat) в папке bin папки WildFly. При запущенном standalone.

Сначала через adduser надо создать пользователя, потом уже заходить через web

```
cd /opt/wildfly-8.2.0.Final/bin
./add-user.sh
```

Выбираем `a`

```
What type of user do you wish to add? 
 a) Management User (mgmt-users.properties) 
 b) Application User (application-users.properties)
(a):
```

Заполняем поля

```
Username :
Password :
```

Оставляем поле привязки юзера к группе пустЬм

```
What groups do you want this user to belong to? (Please enter a comma separated list, or leave blank for none)[ ]:
```

Соглашаемся:

```
About to add user 'user' for realm 'ManagementRealm'
Is this correct yes/no? yes
```

Если не будет осуществляться Remote Connection смело жмем `no`

```
Is this new user going to be used for one AS process to connect to another AS process? 
e.g. for a slave host controller connecting to the master or for a Remoting connection for server to server EJB calls.
yes/no? no
```

Все, можно переходить в настройки WildFly в браузере и пользоваться сервисом